# ContextMenuStrip.Opening event Handler fires with e.cancel already True

Tags: vb.net, contextmenustrip

The first time that my ContextMenuStrip.Opening event is fired on my form, e.cancel is already True.
Why is it doing this? I would expect e.cancel to be False, the way it is the other times it is fired.
This is causing problems when the ContextMenuStrip doesn't appear when I want it to.

Comment: A question like this requires [this](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem: I'm populating the ContextMenuStrip within the Opening event, so the first time it is called it is empty and optimizes to e.Cancel = True. I just stick "e.cancel = False" in there and I'm good.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229721.aspx

(spent the whole day searching, then find the answer as soon as I post the question...)